# Зачем нужен Express.js? Я понимаю он нужен для упрощения работы с Node.js в плане создания сервера

Tags: node.js, сервер, express

А зачем нам нужно создавать этот сервер? Разве мы не можем просто создать сайт или приложение и залить на хостинг? Разве сервер это не компьютер в дата-центре к которому подключаются удалённо? То что мы делаем у себя на ноутбуках в, например, VSCode не очень на это похоже

Comment: Вы путаете понятие сервер как железо и сервер как приложение.

Comment: Будьте добры, объясните в чём разница и для чего нам нужен веб-сервер-приложение? Вот написали мы его на Express и что дальше? Что проихсодит, как мы можем это использвать?

Comment: Сервером может быть абсолютно любой компьютер, даже ваш ноутбук, даже ваш телефон в кармане, даже лампочка в люстре (если она "умная" с вайфаем). Для того, чтобы сервер работал и делал какие-то полезные дела (например, обрабатывал запросы к веб-сайту), на нём должна быть запущена какая-то программа, которая будет делать эти самые полезные дела. Express как раз и является одной из таких программ. Но вы можете взять любую другую подходящую вам программу, вас никто не ограничивает.

Comment: Хостинг отличается только тем, что полезные программы на нём установлены заранее и обслуживаются администраторами хостинга. Обычно такой программой для сайтов является веб-сервер Apache. Если он вас устраивает - ну и хорошо, брать Express вас никто не заставляет

Comment: И да, сервером может быть ещё и калькулятор, если придумать ему способ подключения к интернету, вот недавно новость была https://habr.com/ru/news/t/567542/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На железном сервере должна работать программа, которая будет принимать и обрабатывать запросы браузера и отсылать ему ответы — будь то создаваемые динамически, будь то просто в виде содержимого статических залитых файлов. Когда мы запрашиваем страничку, запрос ведь уходит не в пустоту — он идёт на определённый ip-адрес и порт, и этот порт должен кто-то слушать. Вот эта программа, которая постоянно слушает порт на железном сервере, получает запросы и отсылает ответы, и называется тоже сервером. Один из разновидностей сервера — это написанный при помощи Express скрипт, его запускает Node.js и он состоит из инструкций, что делать с запросами и как на них отвечать. Express это просто набор готовых средств (библиотека), при помощи которых такой скрипт можно написать быстрее, лучше и надёжнее, чем с нуля, пользуясь только базовыми модулями Node.js.